# pivot_wider is not collapsing rows

Tags: r, datatable, pivot

I'm working with a rather large dataframe.
I need to use pivot_wider as follows

```
imf_ifs_data=pivot_wider(imf_ifs_longer,names_from = indicatorcode, values_from = value)
```

But this returns a dataframe with lists, so I saw examples and tried this

```
imf_ifs_data=imf_ifs_longer %>%
  select(-c(indicatorname))%>%
  #group_by(countryname) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = indicatorcode, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

The problem is that the result here is a dataframe where the rows are not collapsed.

Here's a sample of the input data

```
> dput(imf_ifs_longer[c(1:15),c(1:6)])
structure(list(name = c("Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", 
"Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", 
"Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica"), 
    countrycode = c(321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 
    321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L, 321L), indicatorname = c("Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
    "Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index"
    ), indicatorcode = c("EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", 
    "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", 
    "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX", 
    "EREER_IX", "EREER_IX"), date = c("X1977M11", "X1977M12", 
    "X1978M1", "X1978M2", "X1978M3", "X1978M4", "X1978M5", "X1978M6", 
    "X1978M7", "X1978M8", "X1978M9", "X1978M10", "X1978M11", 
    "X1978M12", "X1979M1"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 98.5739799661449)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's a sample of the data I get from the second version of pivot_wider

```
structure(list(name = c("Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", 
"Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", 
"Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", "Costa Rica"
), indicatorname = c("Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index", 
"Exchange Rates, Real Effective Exchange Rate based on Consumer Price Index, Index"
), date = c("2023M5", "2023M6", "2023M7", "2023M8", "2023M9", 
"2023M10", "2023M11", "2023M12", "2024M1", "2024M2", "1977M11", 
"1977M12", "1978M1", "1978M2", "1978M3"), countryname = c("Dominica", 
"Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", 
"Dominica", "Dominica", "Dominica", "Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", 
"Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", "Costa Rica"), time = structure(c(19478, 
19509, 19539, 19570, 19601, 19631, 19662, 19692, 19723, 19754, 
2861, 2891, 2922, 2953, 2981), class = "Date"), EREER_IX = c(94.0485257761888, 
93.9416527401942, 92.2607108467543, 91.9934431700547, 93.5960429917284, 
93.7240955617686, 92.7756740426763, 92.088492678905, 91.9458324906238, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ENDE_XDC_USD_RATE = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: if you hve a list for each cell, perhaps consider aggregating ie, into a character/ find mean/sum/length etc

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: The dataframe with lists is the results of pivot_wider where `list` is taken as the aggregation function. ie `values_fn = list` within the `pivot_wider` function. Now you said you do not want `list` but you did not give a reason as to why you do not want a list. perhaps consider using `values_fn = toString` or any other function that can work in your case. eg `values_fn = length` `values_fn = first` etc. But you have to state exactly what you want in order to get help. Post  the table that shows what you want

Comment: The dput of the data you get is irrelevant as one can use the code to get that. If the code is producing incorrect results, then the dput of the incorrect results is not worth it. Just include the dput of data, and a table of what you want at the end.

Comment: Just updated the question to show the resulting dataframe

Comment: Pivot wider doesn't collapse rows, can you include desired output?